# Cassandra: get last with a non-null value in a column

Tags: cassandra, cql, cql3

I have a Cassandra table where each column can contain a value or a NULL. But if it contains a NULL, I know that all the next values in that column are also NULL.

Something like this:

```
+------------+---------+---------+---------+
|       date | column1 | column2 | column3 |
+------------+---------+---------+---------+
| 2017-01-01 |       1 |     'a' |    NULL |
| 2017-01-02 |       2 |     'b' |    NULL |
| 2017-01-03 |       3 |    NULL |    NULL |
| 2017-01-04 |       4 |    NULL |    NULL |
| 2017-01-05 |    NULL |    NULL |    NULL |
+------------+---------+---------+---------+
```

I need a query that, for a given column, returns the date of the last column with a non-null value. In this case:

- For column1, '2017-01-04'
- For column2, '2017-01-02'
- For column3, no result returned.

In SQL it would be something like this:

```
SELECT date
FROM my_table
WHERE column1 IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1
```

Is it possible in any way, or should I break the table into one table for each column to avoid the NULL situation at all?

Answer (score 2):

**tldr; Create a new table that tracks this separately.**

This would only be possible if 'column 1' was part of the primary key, with secondary indexes or with a materialized view.

You don't want your primary key to have nulls.  As an aside make sure you're writing 'UNSET' inplace of null to the rest of your table.  This should be handled by the driver but some drivers are not terribly mature.  Writing nulls is effectively a delete operation and will cause tombstones.

Secondary indexes come with performance problems as potentially they hit the entire cluster and don't scale very well beyond a certain point.

Materialized views are being deprecated, so probably avoid those.

You are likely better served by creating a separate table that tracks this exact functionality.  This would mean multiple writes and multiple reads but would avoid large table scans and secondary indexes.

I'm going to assume your partition isn't by date and that you've got wide rows because it makes this simpler but this is what that would look like.

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
  partition bigint,
  date text,
  column1 bigint,
  column2 text,
  column3 text,
PRIMARY KEY(partition, date);

CREATE TABLE offset_tracker(
  partition bigint,
  date text,
PRIMARY KEY(partition);
```

Here you would do a `select date FROM offset_tracker WHERE partition=x` to get your 'largest date with values'.